# Are there other trusted download sources for Eclipse Ganymede 3.4.2? It's no longer available on eclipse.org!

Tags: eclipse, ganymede

Eclipse.org took it off for some reason. When trying to download Ganymede, the server says the files are not there. I need it for Mac OS X Cocoa 32 bit. J2EE or the lightweight version.

> Eclipse downloads - file unavailable
>
> The selected file is invalid, or it is
>   no longer available for download.
>
> This happens when the file is part of
>   a nightly or development build. If so,
>   please return to the project's home
>   page and download a newer version.
>
> Go back.

Now the problem is, it seems no one thought it would be useful to offer eclipse for download, since eclipse.org already does. But they don't. That sucks. You know any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't download a package directly from the downloads site, you can use a BitTorrent client to download one of the [Eclipse torrents](http://build.eclipse.org/technology/phoenix/torrents/). Torrents are available for most package/platforms. I tried to get the Java EE Cocoa package and it started fine.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK (Eclipse Classic) is available from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ (I just downloaded the 3.4.2 Mac OS X Carbon SDK from there).

Comment: perfect! thanks mate! nobody will believe me it took +1 hour to find a eclipse download source.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was looking for that exact download today as well (please don't ask why...), anyway, I found it here: http://archive.eclipse.org/technology/epp/downloads/release/ganymede/SR2/

This lists all available downloads for Ganymede SR2 (CPP, Java, Java EE, ...), for Windows, Linux 32, Linux 64 and Mac OS X (Carbon).